# Aggregate multiple columns into array

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, array-agg

Suppose I have a table like the following

| user | score_1 | score_2 | score_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 80 | 100 |
| 1 | 80 | null | 80 |
| 2 | 95 | 90 | 65 |

I would like to aggregate the 3 scores columns into an array. The result will look like (the order does not matter)

| user | scores |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [100,80,100,80,null,80] |
| 2 | [95,90,65] |

I know I can take `union` of (user, score1), (user, score2) and (user,score3) and then do `array_agg` on top of that. I am wondering if there is a more efficient way.

Comment: you cannot have null as an element of array in final output! so you should adjust your expectations!

Comment: You can `array_agg` first and then `array_concat`, but you need to decide how you want to handle `nulls`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below

```
select user, array_agg(score) scores
from your_table
unpivot (score for col in (score_1, score_2, score_3))
group by user
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason preserving null is a must for you - you can use below trick - but note - the output is not an array and rather string

```
select user, 
  translate(format('%t', array_agg(struct(score_1, score_2, score_3))), '()', '') scores
from your_table
group by user
```

or even simpler

```
select user, 
  format('%t', array_concat_agg([score_1,score_2,score_3])) scores
from your_table
group by user
```

with same output for both above

[image]